# writing a bash script to loop over alphabet and insert arguments into string

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script to loop over the alphabet and insert the letters as an argument in a string. This is what I've tried:

```
for i in {A..Z}
do
        screen -d -m bash -c 'python ~/directory/script.py  $i '  //$i is supposed to evaluate to the letter
done
```

I am missing how to enter the argument in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the single quotes around your `'python...` line with double quotes.

Bash won't perform any expansion on strings enclosed in single quotes, which is why `$i` is not being parsed as you want.

Comment: Yes it worked. What is the explanation for why it worked this way and no the other?

Comment: @kolonel Because bash performs expansion on things like `$variables` within strings enclosed by double quotes, and does not perform this expansion on strings enclosed by single quotes.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash.